# Regarding Assignment of Input and Target in Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, ocr

I am designing an algorithm for OCR using a neural network. I have 100 images([40x20] matrix) of each character so my input should be 2600x800. I have some question regarding the inputs and target.

1) is my input correct? and can all the 2600 images used in random order?

2) what should be the target? do I have to define the target for all 2600 inputs?

3) as the target for the same character is single, what is the final target vector? 
(26x800) or (2600x800)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your input should be correct. You have (I am guessing) 26 characters and 100 images of size 800 for each, therefore the matrix looks good. As a side note, that looks pretty big input size, you may want to consider doing PCA and using the eigenvalues for training or just reduce the size of the images. I have been able to train NN with 10x10 images, but bigger== more difficult. Try, and if it doesn't work try doing PCA.
2. (and 3) Of course, if you want to train a NN you need to give it inputs with outputs, how else re you going to train it? You ourput should be of size `26x1` for each of the images, therefore the output for training should be `2600x26`. In each of the outputs you should have 1 for the character index it belongs and zero in the rest.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 1) i am Planning to apply feature extraction in future so that will reduce my vector size. but mean while i shall reduce the image size to 10x10. i will also go through PCA. 2) can i set target matrix of strings? i mean instead of 26x1 for each image can i use (1x1 char)?

Comment: @SAGARJANI I am not an expert in NN, just have played a bit with them. As far as I know, no, you should use doubles. At piratical output will give you  a number close to 1 (but not 1 in general) in the correct character and numbers close to zero in the incorrect. Generally youll try to find the max of the outputs ant that would be the character recognized.